# Constraint to only allow unique value in a group

Tags: postgresql

I have a table in PostgreSQL 12 with columns "sample", "group", "value". There can be multiple samples in a group. Is it possible to implement a constraint so that each group can only have one distinct value?

EDIT:
This is for a rather complex materialized view, where I would like to make sure that there are no samples in a group that has a value that differ from the other samples. In that sense "value" should be a property of the group in this specific context, but that isn't always the case in the database. The use case is that samples are biological samples taken from different tissues ("value") and groups are e.g. "treated" and "control", and I would like to make sure that there aren't a mix of tissues within one group.

This should be ok:
`('sample1', 'group1', 'value1'), ('sample2', 'group1', 'value1'), 'sample3', 'group2', 'value2')`. Here there are two samples in group 1, but they both have the same value.

This should not be ok:
`('sample1', 'group1', 'value1'), ('sample2', 'group1', 'value2'), 'sample3', 'group2', 'value2')`

This should fail because the two samples in group 1 have different values.

I think some of the confusion came from that I used "unique" in the original post when I was talking about distinct values, but this has nothing to do with `UNIQUE`. For this to work a `CHECK` constraint for a row being added would depend on several other existing rows. I don't know if that works? Or if there should be a trigger maybe? I guess there could be an issue with race conditions on bulk inserts?

Comment: What exactly is "one unique value", is `('group1', 1), ('group1', 2)` OK?. If yes this sounds like a standard unique index on `("group", value)`

Comment: No, COUNT DISTINCT(group, value) = 1.

Comment: That's a unique index on `("group", value)`

Comment: Oh :) I thought that would mean that there could be only one row for each combination of "group" and "sample". Thanks a lot then!

Comment: Yes, that's what it does, and that's what your "count" example does as well

Comment: Sorry, I'm in the process of learning SQL. I mean that `('sample1', 'group1', 1), ('sample2', 'group1', 1)` should be ok, but `('sample1', 'group1', 1), ('sample2', 'group1', 2)` shouldn't.

Comment: Then you just want a unique index `value`

Comment: No, because there could be `('sample3', 'group2', 2)` as well.

Comment: Then it's a unique index over all three columns

Comment: No, because then `('sample1', 'group1', 1), ('sample2', 'group1', 2)` would be considered fine. I mean like GROUP by "group" COUNT(DISTINCT(value))=1.

Comment: Please provide a fiddle with several records and show what you want and, more importantly, why? I've read the thread and am still puzzled as to what exactly has to be `UNIQUE` in combination with what!

Comment: You just need to do some normalization. Remove value from this table and add anew table with group, value as columns and group as the UNIQUE key (or PK).

Comment: Verace, the OP means that `SELECT count(DISTINCT value) FROM table GROUP BY group ;` should return only 1s.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ - The database is normalized, but this is for a materialized view that adds denormalization for performance. The "value" is a property of a sample, not a group, but I need to ensure that only samples with the same "value" gets assigned to each group in the view. Your interpretation of what I'm looking for is correct :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CHECK constraints cannot use subqueries, so you have to use a trigger:

```
CREATE FUNCTION check_one_value_per_group() RETURNS TRIGGER
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM my_table
               WHERE "group" = NEW."group"
                 AND value <> NEW.value;
              ) THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'different values in group %', NEW."group";
    END IF;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$;

CREATE CONSTRAINT TRIGGER one_value_per_group
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OF "group", value ON my_table
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE FUNCTION check_one_value_per_group();
```